# Why does Azure SQL Database and MS SQL Server documentation say sequences are type sysname when they can be configured as anything?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, database-sequence

I was looking at the examples and types while seeing how to use the SEQUENCE command in T-SQL (Azure SQL Database, SQL Server, etc.), but when it lists the types SEQUENCE can be configured as (INT, BIGINT, TINYINT, etc.), it mentions that its "*type is sysname*".

I know what sysname is (for the most part), but isn't SEQUENCE the type I specify (INT, BIGINT, etc.), and not sysname?

What am I missing? I feel like I'm missing something crucial to my understanding of all this.

Thanks.  Sorry for the newbie question -- I know I am one right now.

Here is the page I'm speaking of:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The **NAME** of the `SEQUENCE` is of type `sysname` - not the values the `SEQUENCE` will return ..... (those are integer types)

Comment: From the docs: *sequence_name* - Specifies the unique name by which the sequence is known in the database. Type is **sysname**.

Comment: It's actually BIGINT (not INT) data type, but I get what you're saying.  Noted.

Comment: BIGINT by default, I meant (sorry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As marc_s said: The NAME of the SEQUENCE is of type sysname.

let me summarize:

1. **sequence_name**: Specifies the unique name by which the sequence is known in the database. Type is sysname.  Not the data type.
2. The `bigint` the default data type of sequence if you don't set it.

[image]

Please don't mix the name type and the data type.

You can reference this documents:

1. [Sequence Numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15).
2. [Sequence Properties (General Page)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-properties-general-page?view=sql-server-ver15).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Funny how things seem alien until we understand them and then they seem easy ;)